# .htaccess: rewrite nothing to index

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite if $1 is nothing to 'index'?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +ExecCGI

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !/assets
RewriteRule (.*)  index.php?p=$1 [QSA]

</IfModule>
```

Example:

If I go to mysite.com/test the output is

> Array ( [p] => test )

And when I go to mysite.com the output is:

> Array ( [p] => )

So, how can I rewrite $1 to 'index' when I go to mysite.com? Like this:

mysite.com:

> Array ( [p] => index )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(assets|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ index.php?p=index [L,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(assets|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?p=$1 [L,QSA]
```